# Is it legal to pose as a competitor's customer?

Tags: united-states, intellectual-property, internet, fraud

If company X wants to find out information about company Y's online product, is it illegal for X to hire a contractor to pose as a customer using false details? Assuming no documents are signed, has fraud or any other offense been committed if the contractor gains access to non-public information (or to Y's product itself) if company Y would not have provided that access knowing the contractor was affiliated with company X? If so, who is the guilty party?

Comment: Perhaps the contractor should just buy the product using actual details, but company X should pick someone who is not obviously affiliated with company X.  Does company Y routinely ask its customers whether they are affiliated with company X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Online versus brick and mortar does not matter. It sounds like fraud. First, you are knowingly making a false representation of fact, and this is a material fact (that is, it matters to the other party whether you are a customer or not). Your falsehood is intended to get the other part to act on that false representation, and providing this information injures the other party. [This article](https://www.mitchell-attorneys.com/common-law-fraud) gives an overview of the elements of fraud. Signatures are not required for there to be fraud. It is not illegal to pose as a company's customer: it is illegal do so in order to get something that they would not have otherwise provided.

Comment: Reading this, I get the impression that a manufacturer of (for example) soft drinks cannot purchase a competing soft drink without identifying that the purchaser is affiliated with the manufacturer. But nothing stops any employee of Coca-Cola from going to the store and buying a bottle of Pepsi.

Comment: A previous company I worked for had a lawsuit involving intellectual property theft, where the competitor had sent software engineers to use and copy the functionality of our systems. So this may cause a lawsuit, regardless of the results.

Answer (score 1):

Before disclosing non-public information, the Second Company would very likely have the contractor/fake-customer sign a legally binding NDA agreement.

The disclosure of the non-public information back to the First Company would be a Breach of Contract.

If the Second Company somehow failed to get an NDA or MOU or other document in place, the fake-customer has no obligations to keep information they learned secret, nor even to represent themselves honestly and transparently.

Contrary to @user6726, I disagree that Fraud is supported.